# Group a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have an one-dimensional array `A`, such that `0 <= A[i] <= 11`, and I want to map `A` to an array `B` such that

```
for i in range(len(A)):
    if 0 <= A[i] <= 2: B[i] = 0
    elif 3 <= A[i] <= 5: B[i] = 1
    elif 6 <= A[i] <= 8: B[i] = 2
    elif 9 <= A[i] <= 11: B[i] = 3
```

How can implement this efficiently in `numpy`?

Comment: Both arrays are one-dimensionnal, and that code is in a for-loop ?

Comment: @azro thanks for pointing out. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an int division by `//3`, and that is the most performant solution

```
A = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11])
B = A // 3

print(A)  # [0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
print(B)  # [0  0  0  1  1  1  2  2  2  3  3  3]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like dividing the values of the A[i] by 3 'cause you're sorting out them 3 by 3, 0-2 divided by 3 go answer 0, 3-5 go answer 1, 6-8 divided by 3 is equal to 2, and so on

I built a little schema here:

`A[i] -->  0-2.`  divided by 3 = 0, what you wnat in array B[i] is 0, so it's ok
`A[i] --> 3-5.`  divided by 3 = 1, and so on. Just use a method to make floor the value, so that it don't become float type.

Comment: good thinkin' np.array([2,5,6,7,8,11])//3
=> array([0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3])

Answer (score 1):

Answers provided by others are valid, however I find this function from numpy quite elegant, plus it allows you to avoid for loop which could be quite inefficient for large arrays

```py
import numpy as np

bins = [3, 5, 8, 9, 11]
B = np.digitize(A, bins)
```

Comment: Nice but about 10x times slower than `//3`

Comment: I think this function is very helpful when the numbers are not in an equal gap of 3 for example.

Comment: right @azro, but it is a general purpose solution. If a single interval don't respect the length-3 rule, other solutions won't be 'scalable'

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
C = np.zeros(12, dtype=np.int)
C[3:6] = 1
C[6:9] = 2
C[9:12] = 3

B = C[A]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you hope to expand this to a more complex example you can define a function with all your conditions:

```
def f(a):
    if 0 <= a and a <= 2:
        return 0
    elif 3 <= a and a <= 5:
        return 1
    elif 6 <= a and a <= 8:
        return 2
    elif 9 <= a and a <= 11:
        return 3
```

And call it on your array `A`:

```
A = np.array([0,1,5,7,8,9,10,10, 11])
B = np.array(list(map(f, A))) # array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3])
```